# How to handle the "'Course name cannot be empty. (Parameter 'courseName')'"

Tags: c#, window

I'm trying to solve the problem 'Course name cannot be empty. (Parameter 'courseName')'. I am trying different alternatives in C# and could not get the result I want since I'm making a window form that gets the user input's information and store it in the database (Xampp).

I tried to change the code to that was suggested to me and still not get it right. I'm using WindowForms app.

```cs
private string GetTableName(string courseName)
{
    // Trim the course name to remove leading and trailing whitespace
    string trimmedCourse = courseName?.Trim();

    // Check if the trimmed course name is empty or null
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedCourse))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Course name cannot be empty.", nameof(courseName));
    }

    HashSet<string> validCourseNames = new HashSet<string (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        "BSIT",
        "BSCS",
        "ACT",
        "BSE"
    };
    // Check if the trimmed course name is in the list of valid course names
    if (validCourseNames.Contains(trimmedCourse))
    {
        return trimmedCourse;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid course name.", nameof(courseName));
    }   
}
```

Comment: What solution are you looking for then? In the code above the passed parameter _courseName_ is explicitly checked for emptyness and the code throws if it finds it to be empty. If you like it empty remove the checks.

Comment: This block of code is responsible if user chose the appropriate course, then the information will be stored in their respective database table (using xampp as the database) and returning the value to display them in their respective DataGrid view which is for BSIT, BSCS, ACT, BSE. My Course variable is using Combo Box as its input